# Idle не видит фалов на рабочем столе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ввожу обычную команду для открытия txt документа, но как бы я ни старался

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    file = open(text.txt.txt)
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

Может я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Вы должны заключить имя файла в кавычки, например так: `open('text.txt')`, иначе Python считает `text` за переменную и сообщает Вам, что она не определена.